# Fragment with 2 listview dont detect second click

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have a layout with 2 lists, and a `Listfragment` for the controller.

When i click in the first `@android/id:list` detect ok the click, but when i click in the second list, dont detect anything.

I need to implement in other side?

This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_order_workouts, container, false);
        worksListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvWorks);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initCategoryList();
        worksListView.addHeaderView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.work_header, null));
        worksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hol",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initCategoryList() {
        ArrayList<Company> companies = VirteuApplication.getInstance().getCompanies();
        Order currentOrder = VirteuApplication.getInstance().getOrder();
        for (Company company : companies) {
            if (company.getCompany().toLowerCase().equals(currentOrder.getCompany().toLowerCase())) {
                companySelected = company;
                AbstractAdapter adapter = new ParentWorkinfoDataAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), company.getWorktypesNames());
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I change ListFragment for fragment with this code:

```
public class OrderAddWorkCategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    private Company companySelected = null;
    private ListView worksListView;
    private ListView categoriesListView;
    private GetWorksForCompanyApiCall getWorksApiCall;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_order_workouts, container, false);
        categoriesListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvCategories);
        worksListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvWorks);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initCategoryList();
        worksListView.addHeaderView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.work_header, null));
    }

    private void initCategoryList() {
        ArrayList<Company> companies = VirteuApplication.getInstance().getCompanies();
        Order currentOrder = VirteuApplication.getInstance().getOrder();
        for (Company company : companies) {
            if (company.getCompany().toLowerCase().equals(currentOrder.getCompany().toLowerCase())) {
                companySelected = company;
                AbstractAdapter adapter = new ParentWorkinfoDataAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), company.getWorktypesNames());
                categoriesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                categoriesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        ParentWorkinfoDataAdapter.viewHolder vHolder = (ParentWorkinfoDataAdapter.viewHolder) view.getTag();
                        String workName = vHolder.getTextValue();
                        getWorks(workName);
                        getWorksApiCall.execute();
                    }
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void initWorksLists(List<Work> works) {
        AbstractAdapter adapter = new ChildWorkinfoDataAdapter(getActivity(), works, R.layout.list_row_detail);
        worksListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        worksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hol", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getWorks(String workname) {

        getWorksApiCall = new GetWorksForCompanyApiCall(getActivity(), companySelected.get_id(), workname, new ApiResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void success(Object value) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Worktypes[] worktypes = gson.fromJson(value.toString(), Worktypes[].class);
                List<Work> works = new ArrayList<Work>();
                if (worktypes.length > 0 && worktypes[0].getWorktypes().get(0).getWorks() != null) {
                    works = worktypes[0].getWorktypes().get(0).getWorks();
                }

                initWorksLists(works);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(ApiException e) {

            }
        });
        getWorksApiCall.execute();
    }

}
```

But the worksListView dont detect click.

Comment: Which listview are you having the issue with?

Comment: worksListView, categoriesListView works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListFragment` is just a normal `Fragment` that inflates a layout with a `ListView` and displays a `ProgressBar` while bringing the `ListView` to the visible state.

Why don't you use an ordinary Fragment, with a custom layout containing the two `ListView`s aligned as you like, then declare two `ListView` variables for the listwiews and set your OnItemClick or whatever listeners?

Comment: I did it, with same result. I edit my question code:

Comment: Can you post the layout xml you created? Have you assigned the two listviews different ids?

Comment: Looking at your question, I see this: `@android/id:list`.

Comment: I see you are calling `initCategoryList();`. But I don't see where you are calling the init function for the other list.

Comment: In getWorks success callback

Comment: First of all, make sure that `initWorksLists` gets called at all!

Comment: Im sure its called, because set the adapter and show results.